# why is FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: params).start being called only once

Tags: swift, facebook, authentication

I'm trying to obtain certain Facebook info of my test user and this method that I used to obtain the user info only seemed to be called when signing up but not when logging in I want to return these info everytime user log in using Facebook. I'm using the following method in `didCompleteWith` method

```
let params = ["fields" : "email, name, friendlists"]
        let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: params)
        _ = graphRequest?.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if let result = result as? [String:Any]{
                guard let email = result["email"] as? String else {
                    return
                }

                guard let username = result["name"] as? String else {
                    return
                }

                guard let friendList = result["friendlists"] as? String else {
                    return
                }

                print(email, username, friendList)
            }
        })
```

Is there some other method I should use?

**UPDATE**: I believe I'm not using correct parameter for obtaining friends list too.

Comment: _“I believe I'm not using correct parameter for obtaining friends list too.”_ - friendlists only gives you the names of the lists the user has created, nothing more.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, found that the I was providing incorrect argument in graphPath, to access friends list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has no problem. Probably you are not waiting for the completion block to execute. Just wait for a few seconds so that the block can execute.